# Slow blender with 1070?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have a i7 6700K with 16gb and a gtx 1070 and when I'm using blender, it doesn't feel smooth at all when I'm doing a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>  or even trying to change the shading viewport, from texture to no texture, or texture to texture+ light, I have to wait like 5/10 sec before being able to do something.

I have a friend with a 980Ti who has no problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: Keep in mind that the material and rendered preview require to load textures from your hard drive. I/O is slow especially if you're using a HDD and not a SSD.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for your answer :) but yeah i'm on an SSD but i'm using megscan import with the bridge link, is that the problem ?